# Excel Get and Transform from web not picking up newly added columns

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets, powerquery

I'm using a Power Query to load in data from a Google Spreadsheet changelog capturing changes by a department within our orginisation.

I set it up using the method of loading the data in via CSV. I generated a download of the sheet from the file I want to use and use the download link to offer a webquery. This was all working as intended. For purposes of my analysis, I had to add two more columns to this sheet and thus the CSV file.

Now, when I run the query based on the link, the new columns (7 and 8) are not being recognised in the query. If I manually set the source to 8 columns, the data that is in there does not show as well.

I've checked the downloaded CSV (which generates the link). It does contain the data in Notepad and it does pickup the data as well when I load in the downloaded CSV into Power Query.

It's like there's some kind of cache limiting the link to the 6 columns previously used, but I've got no clue how to work around it.

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for code similar to

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\TEMP\5.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```

and remove the

```
, Columns=6
```

part so that you get

```
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\TEMP\5.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```